# Scrapy Traceback 302, list of index error

Tags: python, web-scraping, callback, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** articles of a specific tag, like 'machine-learning' here in Python 2.7. I have the following code:

```
import scrapy
import codecs
import json
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os

def writeTofile(fileName,text):
    with codecs.open(fileName,'w','utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(text)

class MediumPost(scrapy.Spider):
    name='medium_scraper'
    handle_httpstatus_list = [401,400]    
    autothrottle_enabled=True


    def start_requests(self):        
        start_urls = ['https://medium.com/tag/'+self.tagSlug.strip("'")+'/archive/']
        print(start_urls)        
        #Header and cookie information can be got from the Network Tab in Developer Tools
        cookie = {'mhj': 'd4c630604c57a104af8bc98218fb3430145',
                                        'nj': '1',
                                        'ko': '1:J0mnan1t5jlHypyliL8GAY1WNfDvtqZBgmBDr+7STp2QSwyWUz6',
                                        'pi': '233',
                                        'mt': '-874'}
        header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'}
        startDate=datetime.strptime(self.start_date,"%Y%m%d")
        endDate=datetime.strptime(self.end_date,"%Y%m%d")
        delta=endDate-startDate
        print(delta)
        for i in range(delta.days + 1):
            d=datetime.strftime(startDate+timedelta(days=i),'%Y/%m/%d')
            for url in start_urls:
                print(url+d)
                yield scrapy.Request(url+d, method="GET",headers=header,cookies=cookie,callback=self.parse,meta={'reqDate':d})
    
    def parse(self,response):
        response_data=response.text
        response_split=response_data.split("while(1);</x>")
        response_data=response_split[1]
        date_post=response.meta['reqDate']
        date_post=date_post.replace("/","")
        directory=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        writeTofile(directory+"//"+self.tagSlug.replace("-","").strip("'")+"Tag"+date_post+".json",response_data)
```

An message says that:

```
scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://medium.com/tag/machine-learning/archive/2015/07/13> (referer: None)
```

NotImplementedError: MediumPost.parse callback is not defined

But, I'm repeatedly getting errors like:

```
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/home/mkol/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
```

When I try to place, def parse above the def start_requests, I get the indentation error.

as I'm a beginer, I cannot get where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have "MediumPost.parse callback is not defined" issue be course of your editor. Look like python translator do not see function "parse". I think you mixed four spaces and tabulations.
I use PyCharm. May be be course of that I do not have same issue.
It work for me after some changes. I add self.tagSlug, self.start_date, self.end_date.
I edited code using PEP-8 recomendation. It look better now. I removed "prints". It's better to use breakpoints during debugging.
I moved names of variables to Python type. As I remember PEP-8 recomend to you only one type of names (Python type or Java type).

```
import scrapy
import codecs
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os

def writeTofile(file_name, text):
    with codecs.open(file_name, 'w', 'utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(text)

class MediumPost(scrapy.Spider):
    name='medium_scrapper'
    handle_httpstatus_list = [401, 400]
    autothrottle_enabled = True
    tag_slug = 'machine-learning'
    start_date = '20170110'
    end_date = '20181130'

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = ['https://medium.com/tag/' + self.tag_slug.strip("'") + '/archive/']

        #Header and cookie information can be got from the Network Tab in Developer Tools
        cookie = {'mhj': 'd4c630604c57a104af8bc98218fb3430145',
                  'nj': '1',
                  'ko': '1:J0mnan1t5jlHypyliL8GAY1WNfDvtqZBgmBDr+7STp2QSwyWUz6',
                  'pi': '233',
                  'mt': '-874'}

        header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'}

        startDate = datetime.strptime(self.start_date, "%Y%m%d")
        endDate = datetime.strptime(self.end_date, "%Y%m%d")
        delta = endDate - startDate

        for i in range(delta.days + 1):
            d = datetime.strftime(startDate + timedelta(days=i), '%Y/%m/%d')

            for url in start_urls:
                print(url + d)
                yield scrapy.Request(url + d, headers=header, cookies=cookie, meta={'req_date': d})

    def parse(self,response):
        response_data = response.text
        response_split = response_data.split("while(1);</x>")
        response_data = response_split[0]
        date_post = response.meta['req_date']
        date_post = date_post.replace("/", "")
        directory = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

        writeTofile(directory + "//" + self.tag_slug.replace("-", "").strip("'") + "Tag" + date_post + ".json", response_data)
```